# Reference Request: Distributed Systems Systems

Tags: reference-request, distributed-systems, books

I recently finished *Operating System Concepts*. As a follow-up for self-teaching, I am looking for a book on distributed systems (not theory). I've found [Tanenbaum's text](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132392275) but it has rather poor reviews. I'm hoping for something with a similar flavor to *Concepts*: focusing on the general principals and concepts for building systems, without getting *too* technical.

Comment: Define "too technical".

Comment: Google for "distributed systems $yourfavoriteuni" and check their syllabus. It usually contains recommended books. [Here's something from MIT](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-824-distributed-computer-systems-engineering-spring-2006/syllabus/)